# How to make GM/GMO children exceptionally loyal to one another?

Tags: science-based, science-fiction, psychology, genetic-engineering

In the not so distant future a man builds a remote doom fortress to design, create, and raise GM/GMO children.  His plan is to nurture geniuses who can enact his dastardly plan to wipe out humanity, and for his children to repopulate the earth.

The man precisely designs his (let's say ten) children, and raises them in isolation, doing everything he can to make them as smart and capable as possible home schooled until he sends them out to the real world to get some higher education and life experience and networking to achieve his goals.

EDIT: Please note that the use of "children" is not a specific age reference to pre-pubescence (I rather unobservantly didn't see that this could be severely misconstrue), simply that they are the man's "children" or offspring since he created them.
**How can his complete control over their nature and nurture be used to achieve the following:**

1. The children must be created and raised to have a deeply genuine love and empathy for each other - which importantly cannot be easily translated into empathy for outsiders.
2. The children must be created and raised to find each other sexually attractive and for this to overcome the natural tendency for "siblings" (psychologically; those raised together) to be repulsed by each other.
   **IMPORTANT EDIT: this means relations between the individuals as teenagers or young adults, as is normal.  "Children" is not used here to mean age specific reference!!**
3. The children must be created and raised to ensure they are loyal to each other, regardless of whether the aforementioned techniques work.
4. Techniques should ideally be subtle and work in ways the children cannot anticipate, and must not be overtly forced or negative.  They must not infringe upon the children's intelligence.  The aim is to have these techniques make the children return to each other, and home, and their objective.

I would appreciate answers based in psychology and biological sciences (genetics, neurology, etc) to understand the processes which are a problem to achieving the goals, and so how they could be overcome.

In this case GM/GMO (Genetically Modified/Genetically Modified Organism, or "designer baby") is someone whose genome has been planned with great precision, and then has been created as a "test tube" baby in some sort of artificial womb. They do not have a biological or even surrogate mother, and they might even be a synthetic organism (a la craig venter).

Comment: This question kind of reminds me of the movie _Never Let Me Go._

Comment: Give them proximity related hive intelligence. The closer they are the greater the sum of the parts.

Taking that to the illogical limit makes this more a plot for a porno than SF though.

Comment: @Schwern "justify" is not the right word.  Does that mean to say that any story which involves something negative endorses it?  Come on.  The whole premise as outlined clearly implies this is bad because it helps alienate individuals from each other, since the only way the man can devise a genocidal system is to ensure the people who go through with the plan are created to be loyal to the plan.  Plenty of examples exist of cults and dystopias where sexuality is used as a means of control and conformity.

Comment: Your footnote star turns into a bullet format code.

Comment: Evil genius homeschools children in isolation, raising them to go forth into the world and take it over?  Best sitcom ever:  Unbreakable Kimmy Schmidt meets Big Bang Theory. I want royalties!

Comment: Looks like [Dark Angel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Angel_%28TV_series%29) TV series.

Comment: @Harper  I laughed out loud when I read your comment.

Comment: `dastardly plan to wipe out humanity` of which he is a part of. I can see this plan hilariously backfire when his children come to eliminate the first/last human on the list.

Comment: This looks like a call for some really bad pedophiliac incest erotica disguised as sci-fi.

Comment: While I have no problem with the subject matter it _does_ seem to me like the question is primarily opinion based.

Comment: @AndreiROM please explain?

Comment: @inappropriateCode - because we are not critiquing your ideas. Instead, we are generating ideas, and you're selecting the one which sounds best to you. In other words opinion based.

Comment: @AndreiROM I really don't understand that.  I put science-based, psychology, and genetic engineering in the tags with the hope it would encourage answers influenced by those.  I haven't selected any answers yet.  I'm reading and waiting, and just remarking that people not liking the subject matter isn't cause to say the question is invalid when it's a question of the nature of human behaviour (scientifically based analysis) and if that can be influenced in certain ways given the context.  If there's a way I should have phrased the question better I'd appreciate being told?

Comment: Let's say I asked you what ingredients might make the _best sandwich_. One person will say BLT, another person hates tomatoes, but loves mayo, etc. Which answer is best? Is that an objective way of determining this? Similarly, you're asking us what the best way to brainwash these clones is. There's no textbook answer, and you're not providing any parameters such as, for example "anything sex related is off the table". So one person might answer that they need to have chips implanted in their brains, another that it's all down to manipulation of another kind. Who's right? Who's wrong? Opinions.

Comment: As to how to phrase it, I think a better way to look at it is that you need to better _frame_ the question. Provide some parameters which seem likely, or desirable to you. Tell us what you expect from a _good_ answer, so that people don't waste their time going off on a tangent which you disregard out of hand. That's what the purpose of that close reason (opinion based) is. Now, as you can see, people will still answer opinion based questions, because some of them are a pretty challenging, or fun, but they are still out of scope. So maybe apply these lessons for your next question :-)

Comment: @AndreiROM thank you for clarifying that!  I understand now, and will have to reconsider how to frame the question and what criteria I state for it.  Because of that, would it be better to delete the post in the meantime?

Comment: Don't delete it - people have already answered it. I would suggest looking at the answers provided, deciding what sort of direction you want to go in, and editing the question. The community can then vote to reopen it. If you're not attracting quality answers you can also offer a bounty (50 rep, for example), but I don't think that's necessary yet.

Comment: I guess I don't understand why the siblings section is necessary.  Nothing you are doing requires them to be siblings (by blood).

Comment: I suggest looking up naked mole rat communities and how they interact

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Engineer them to excrete pheromones that have no effect on humans but attract the opposite sex from among their genetic siblings.  Then increase their sense of smell so that they find the natural odor of unmodified humans repulsive.

Answer (score 2):

He actually wont need to do much.  From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_sexual_attraction):

> People tend to select mates that are like themselves, which is known as assortative mating. This holds both for physical appearances and mental traits. People commonly rank faces similar to their own as more attractive, trustworthy, etc. than average.
>   ...
>   GSA is rare between people raised together in early childhood due to a reverse sexual imprinting known as the Westermarck effect, which desensitizes them to later close sexual attraction. It is hypothesized that this effect evolved to prevent inbreeding

The mere separation of his children may be sufficient for his "dastardly plan" to work out.  Of course, he'll still have to deal with the fact that it's generally accepted that one needs a population of about 5,000 to avoid inbreeding issues, but hey.  10 is a start =)

Comment: Doesn't the GMO, with adding enough mutation resistance, solve the inbreeding = mutation damage stacking, issues? ... Although, it doesn't remove issues of a small genepool.

Comment: It could if the "father" is a perfect being who makes no mistakes.  The "perfect genome" has not yet been sequenced by mother nature.  She's always tinkering with it.  The human genome, like that of most species, was never designed to deal with such a severe bottleneck in genetic material.  Although, if these "children" are sufficiently altered as to no longer qualify as human, all bets are off, so maybe it could work!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that he should just raise them naturally just mines the Incest taboo.  If they never discover that sibling sexual interaction is unusual or wrong then they probably won't develop the taboo on there own, if he keeps them in a enclosed society with out access to the outside world they will have no other people to interact with sexually but them selves. With no else to "do it" with and with no developed incest taboo, nature will do all the work for him.